# Example of tasks in ansible that does NOT require python2.7?

Tags: python, ansible

I have the following ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: myhosts
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: just a test message
```

When I run that from command line I get:

```
PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

So that works just fine. But if I add:

```
- hosts: myhosts
  gather_facts: no


  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: just a test message
    - name: Another task
      command: echo "Do whatever you want to"
```

It fails with:

```
TASK [Another task] *******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to localhost closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/sandbox/ansible-vps/foo.retry

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

From what i have googled Ansible requires python2.7 for most of its functionality - which I currently don't have installed. So is the above error caused by missing Python2.7 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is the above error caused by missing Python2.7

Yes. Ansible requires Python for almost every module except: `raw`, `script`.

You can install Python with `raw` module first and then proceed with other tasks. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071176/2795592).

Example of tasks that don't require Python:

```
- hosts: myhosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: just a test message
    - name: Another task
      raw: /bin/bash -c 'some-command with-parameter'
      register: cmd_res
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cmd_res.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Ok, when I run you updated example - using raw instead of command - the text "Do whatever  you want to" is not printed to console, it just says changed: [localhost]. So how do I use raw to execute a bash command on the remote?

Comment: I've update example with debug output to check results. Or you can execute playbook with increased verbosity (`-vv`) to see modules' output.